# Monitor Windows Terminal Sessions from Linux/Mac

Tags: linux, windows-server-2003, remote-desktop, rdp

I'm writing some scripts to make remote connections to a Windows 2003 server a bit more user-friendly, and in doing this I want to see who's logged in already. In Windows, I could use qwinsta.exe to do this, even for remote servers. So it is exposed somehow, but I couldn't find a matching command line tool for Unix.

Lacking such a tool, I could install an ssh server on the machine and call it remotely, parsing the output or write a small service of my own that would expose this via http, if I don't want full-blown ssh access.

Do I have to do this, or is there already a tool for querying terminal services remotely?

Comment: Sounds like something that might be possible to do using WS-Management...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a simple command line access to the windows server,
there is [**freeSSHd**](http://www.freesshd.com/) for that.

It will allow you to login to the Windows Server using your `ssh` client and run commands remotely. You can then run `qwinsta.exe` and use its output.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find a suitable means to query Windows WMI from a non-windows host (and there are some available e.g. [here's one for Linux](http://forums.cacti.net/about11752.html)), then you can get the current sessions by querying [Win32_LogonSessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394189%28VS.85%29.aspx). The downside to this method is the WMI service needs to be active on your target.

The other (maybe easier) alternative is as you mentioned, use an SSH connection to run the qwinsta command locally, and grab/parse that output.

Them thar folks over at stack overflow are all brainy when it comes to the programmin', they'll probably have additional insights.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused, do you want to see who's logged into the unix machine or who's logged into the windows machine.  For Unix, just use who.